# Barcodes PageUp and PageDown Keys

Tags: c#, barcode, barcode-scanner, keyboard-events, barcode-printing

In my application I use Page Up and Page Down as navigation keys. Works with powerpoint presentation pointers.

My software also uses barcodes, with a barcode scanner working as an enumerated keyboard. What I am trying to do, is trying to create a barcode, that can be scanned and trigger the same key press as the PageUp and PageDown keys.

Comment: Any code? Have you try something yet?

Comment: The code is a little irrelevant at the moment. I have my window key up event triggering, to see if any of the navigation keys are pressed. 

So I'm trying to make my barcode scanner input a "Page Up" key press to be picked up by the event.

This is more a question on encoding different barcode formats.

Comment: Well, hope this package will help you. http://freebarcode.codeplex.com/

Comment: I don't think you can encode the page up/page down key character but you can come up with some kind of special character sequence and look for that in your application and then simulate a page up or page down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Shane, I have solved my problem by introducing a character sequence in my software.

```
%[CMD_PageUp], %[CMD_PageDown] etc.
```

I capture the key press event for when these have been entered to then process the same function that pressing PageUp or PageDown would.